# How can i install react navigation?

Tags: react-native, navigation, react-navigation

I have got the error:
[image: Error image]

I was install  `npm install @react-navigation/native` and

```
npm install react-native-reanimated react-native-gesture-handler react-native-screens react-native-safe-area-context @react-native-community/masked-view
```

but when I run project , emulator throw this error.

Comment: Could you add to your question this error as a text?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using ReactNative version under 0.60, you will need to use

```
  react-native link
```

If you use ReactNative 0.60 or higher, you need to make sure install cocoapods.

```
  npx pod-install ios
```